# Computing negative half power of a bandwidth matrix for multivariate KDE

Tags: multivariate-analysis, matrix, kernel-smoothing, matrix-inverse

I am currently working on a project on density-based clustering algorithms and I am trying to make sense of the formula for a multivariate kernel density estimator [see [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_kernel_density_estimation).

$$
\hat{f}_\mathbf{H}(\mathbf{x})= \frac1n \sum_{i=1}^n K_\mathbf{H} (\mathbf{x} - \mathbf{x}_i),
$$
where

- $\mathbf{x}=(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_d)^{\top}, \mathbf{x}_i=(x_{i1},x_{i2},\dots,x_{id})^{\top} , i \in \{1,2,\dots,n\}$ are $d-$vectors;
- $\mathbf{H}$ is the $d \times d$ bandwidth matrix which is **symmetric** and **positive definite**;
- $K$ is the kernel function which is a symmetric multivariate density,
  where
  $$
  K_{\mathbf{H}}(\mathbf{x}) = |\mathbf{H}|^{-\frac{1}{2}}K(\mathbf{H}^{-\frac{1}{2}}\mathbf{x}).
  $$
  I was wondering, how does one exactly compute $\mathbf{H}^{-\frac{1}{2}}$ in context of the multivariate KDE method? I cannot find any references related to MKDE that specifies how to compute this power.

I would be very grateful if anybody had any suggestions on computing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be shown that every symmetric and positive semidefinite matrix $A$ has a unique symmetric and positive definite square root $A^{1/2}$.  If you've orthogonally diagonalized $A$ as

$A=QDQ^{T}$

where $Q$ is an $n$ by $n$ orthogonal matrix and $D$ is an $n$ by $n$ diagonal matrix with the eigenvalues $\lambda_{1}$, $\lambda_{2}$, $\ldots$, $\lambda_{n}$, on the diagonal, then

$A^{1/2}=QD^{1/2}Q^{T}$

where $D^{1/2}$ is the diagonal matrix obtained from $D$ by taking the square roots of the elements on the diagonal of $D$.

In MATLAB, you can use the built-in function sqrtm() to compute this matrix square root.

In your case, you either computate $H^{-1}$ and then compute the matrix square root, or you could diagonalize $H$ first, and then compute $D^{-1/2}$ and write $H^{-1/2}=QD^{-1/2}Q^{T}$.